# C# Parent - child forms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm having a main window (MainWindow.cs) form which contains a panel (pnlChild), I've created a new control to add my second form (Settings.cs) + controls to the panel:

```
Settings settings = new Settings() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false };
settings.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
pnlChild.Controls.Add(settings);
settings.Show();
```

This is working fine, I have the same in my settings form, which also contains a panel "pnlChild", a child form (Appearance.cs) which contains "Appearance"

```
Settings.Appearance appearance = new Settings.Appearance() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false };
appearance.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
pnlChild.Controls.Add(appearance);
appearance.Show();
```

**Question:** *How can I change a text/update text to the "Settings" and/or "Main" form, when I press a button in the appearance child form?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround that maybe you can refer to. In this demo, I add textboxes named `tbMain` and `tbSettings` in `MainWindows` and `Settings`.

First, define a property in `MainWindow.cs` to access `tbMain`.

```
public TextBox TBM
{
    get { return tbMain; }
    set { tbMain = value; }
}
```

And define a property in `Settings.cs` to access `tbSettings`.

```
public TextBox TBS
{
    get { return tbSettings; }
    set { tbSettings = value; }
}
```

Then we can use [`Application.OpenForms Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1) to get the `MainWindows` and `Settings` instance. And modify the textbox value through the properties defined before.

```
private void btInAppearance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings settings = (Settings)Application.OpenForms["Settings"];
    settings.TBS.Text = "TextInSettings";


    MainWindow main = (MainWindow)Application.OpenForms["MainWindow"];
    main.TBM.Text = "TextInMainWindow";
}
```